# Youtube Streaming (Geographical Location)

Tags: networking, streaming

Is it possible to find out the geographical location (IP Address/host) that I'm streaming a specific Youtube video?

I believe not all videos stream from the same Youtube Cache server, correct?

By nslookup the v1.lscache1.c.youtube.com it seems by unicast I get resolved to a local cache but I doubt that all videos stream from this locations.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Like any site of their size they will made use of a CDN, in their case it's their own that is indeed geographically dispersed. These CDN nodes will also be load-balanced so even playing back one video won't will only tell you about that specific server, also just to add complexity to your question YouTube are perfectly capable of *shifting* servers mid-play, this is actually quite a common practice, one playback could actually be served from servers in different countries.

So given this information I think you're going to be challenged to get what you need, perhaps if you explain what it is you're trying to achieve from a higher-level perspective we may be able to help more?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm trying to find why some Youtube videos are very fast and other very slows. I've tested with some recent uploaded videos (5 min or less) to mitigate the caching across.